# What happens if you expel the Jews?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I haven't been able to find complete informations about expelling the Jews.

- how much gold do you get if you do it?
- how much gold does calling them back cost?
- does being heretic (i.e. Cathar) change anything?

Comment: Today in Arqade question titles...

Answer (score 5):

From the [wiki](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Decisions) :

- Gains 5 time of yearly income in gold, -100 prestige, banish all Jewish courtiers
- Occasional -50 point technology events
- Removes negative opinion modifier from clergy
- Cancels any loan from Jews
- Gains *Expelled Jews* modifier : -2 diplomacy and -10% global tax modifier
- Gains *Arbitrary* if currently owns money from Jews

And obviously, you won't be able to borrow money from them anymore.

Comment: Also, everybody will make jokes on your country seventy years later, and your character will grow a small mustache. If you see what I mean.

Comment: Does banishing all Jewish courtiers work like normal banishment? Do you confiscate their personal wealth? Do they show up at other courts hating you?

Comment: I *think* individual banishment works just the same for Jews. I haven't tested, though.

Comment: The 3rd and 4th points are related, right? The negative opinion modifier its talking about is the "-10 owes money to Jewish moneylenders"? Also missing from the wiki is how long before you can welcome them back; I think I read that it's 10 years, unless a succession happens, which allows the new ruler to welcome them back instantly.

Comment: 3rd indeed looks like a consequence of 4th ; what's cool is that you keep the money. And the wiki *does* state the minimum duration of the banishment : in the page I linked, it's the next line (*Welcome the Jews* event), and says 20 year.

Comment: It's not clear if the modifier stays with the next ruler, though.

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me. To undo the *Expel* decision, either you must have taken it more than 20 years ago, or you must not be the one who took it.

Comment: No mention if being an Heresy changes anything, though.